# How far back can you go back with the Twitter API

Tags: c#, api, twitter, tweetsharp

I have developed a application in c# that fetches in tweets to a database. I'm currently using TweetSharp Wrapper.

Since it has recently been announced that twitter now have indexed all of the previous tweets, which allows you to go back to the very first tweets, i started to wonder if it's possible to go back to a certain time period.

Lets say i want to see all tweets that contains "Microsoft" from the time period 2008-10-10 to 2009-10-10. Is this possible for the Twitter API??? Let alone is it possible with the TweetSharp module??

Any answer is accepted.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumptions are that you are using the *free* version of the Twitter REST API (there are also Twitter Streaming APIs that I have no experience with) and that TweetSharp is just a wrapper over the REST API.

Given that, I'm inclined to think that the query you are requesting ("microsoft since:2008-10-10 until:2009-10-10") is **not possible** for a few reasons:

- Searching with the Twitter REST API only goes back 7 days.
- The number of tweets relating to microsoft tweets in a year will exceed the rate limit

My Source is [Adam Green's Blog: 140Dev, Nov 2013](http://140dev.com/twitter-api-programming-blog/search-api-what-are-the-real-limits-on-tweet-results/). The documentation is a bit vague on exactly how far back the REST API will go. My experiences show that up to the past 7 days. The [rate limits](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits) are pretty explicitly documented, however.

This answer is a over a month late; if you figured out a way to make this work, do share!