# How to get the number of tweets from a given hashtag

Tags: tweepy, hashtag

I'm using the library tweepy. My objective is obtain the number of tweets of a given hashtag related with films of the spanish cinema.

I use the function 'search' with the input parameter: the title of the film.

I would like obtain the hashtag related to this title, and then the number of tweets that was in it.

Can you help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi!! By the moment I have tried this code:

for tweet in tw.search(q = "#Gru", count=100):
   print(tweet.created_at)  
   print(tweet.user.screen_name)  
   print(tweet.text)


But with this code, I only get the last 100 tweets posted related with this hashtag. With the function 'Search' I'm not able to obtain the total number of tweets of a given hashtag.

I have searched others function to do this, but I don't find anything related

Answer (score 1):

you might want to use the `Cursor` class: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/cursor_tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried to use the Cursor class, but with this I can obtain only the tweets related with a given hashtag during 7-10 days ago.
Do you now if with Cursor can i get information older?

Comment: i think that might be a limitation on the twitter api (cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170882/how-far-back-can-you-go-back-with-the-twitter-api )

Comment: Yes.. I have investigated and I have observed this limitation. Do you know another wat to develop this issue? Thanks!!!